# Writing to file wont write

Tags: java, android, file, email, file-io

Just as the title states, Im creating a new file and then sending that file as an email attachment

File Creation Code:

```
newFile = new File("/sdcard/" + TEMPFILENAME);
if (newFile.exists()) {
    newFile.delete();
}
newFile.createNewFile();
for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
    writeFileToStorage(TEMPFILENAME, arrayList.get(j).AccountName, arrayList.get(j).UserName, encryptString(arrayList.get(j).Password));
}
recipient = emailEdit.getText().toString();
new EmailSender().execute();
```

then in my email service class I have the following

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(source);

message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));

messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(handler);
messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

The file is getting sent with the correct name and from the correct recipient/sender but the file is always empty.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Implementation of writeFileToStorage, which works in the app regularly when saving data

```
try {
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fName, MODE_APPEND)));
    bufferedWriter.write(aName);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write(_uName);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write(_pWord);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    Log.d("Wrote: ", ("AccountName: "+ aName + " UserName: " + _uName + " Password: " + _pWord+ " to: " + fName));
} catch (Exception err) {
    String writeError = getString(R.string.write_error);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), writeError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Show the implementation of: `writeFileToStorage`

Comment: Are you *closing* the file?

Comment: Never hardcode root paths. Always use methods to derive top-level directories in Android. Hence, please use `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, etc. Also, never use concatenation to build a file path. Use the `File` constructor that takes the root directory (as a `File`) and the name of the file you want in that directory. Also, please do not clutter up the user's external storage with your files. And, you are not passing the `File` into `writeFileToStorage()`, and so nobody knows where you are writing this data to.

Comment: CommonsWare, the app is a password saving app, if the user upgrades their phone there is no way to transfer the data. This is allowing them to do so. the file gets deleted after the email is sent either way, plus it's only a couple of megabytes of data. getExternalFilesDir is throwing a FileNotFoundException

Comment: Before you send the file by email and on the receiver side discover that you received nothing you could check if the file exists and check its file size.

Comment: Your code is a mess. `new File("/sdcard/" + TEMPFILENAME);` and  `openFileOutput(fName, MODE_APPEND))` do not match. Because the first is external memory and the latter internal.

Comment: Ah see thats what I was unaware of, thank you. I modified the code and now it's writing and sending correctly, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting how you wrote the `writeFileToStorage(...)` Method.

After calling `newFile.createNewFile();` your `newFile` won't get manipulated.

Edit: Your `writeFileToStorage(...)` Method doesnt seem to work. The parameter `fname` is not correct.

Comment: fName is being passed in as TEMPFILENAME and it does pass it in correctly because the attachment the email sends does have the correct name